# Is "slip of an object" a personification?

Tags: word-usage, metaphors, figurative-language

- > On an ordinary day, you might miss this slip of a shop wedged between a veterinary clinic and a grocery store in Paris' popular Bastille.
  >
  > NPR: [The Last Razor Repairman In Paris](https://www.npr.org/sections/parallels/2016/08/21/489765987/the-last-razor-repairman-in-paris)
- > a young and slender person, a slip of a girl

The word seems to be used for people. Can it be used for objects? Is there a rule that prevents it to be used on an inanimate object? Can we use it in poetry, why and when?

Comment: A number of dictionaries include a definition (among 50 other definitions) which is "noun. A long, thin piece of something."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is personification because we are not giving a human attribute to something nonhuman.

Let's look at this entry for *slip*:

> [slip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slip) noun (2)
>
> Definition of slip (Entry 3 of 5)
> 1a : a small shoot or twig cut for planting or grafting : scion
> b : descendant, offspring
> 2 a : a long narrow strip of material
> b : a small piece of paper
> 3 : a young and slender person
> // a *slip* of a girl
>
> (M-W)

We can use *slip* to describe something thin or slender as in 2a. That is how it's used in *slip of a girl* and *slip of a shop*. Both are described as being a *slip* (narrow thing/person). This usage of *of* is common.

> [of](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/of?s=t)
> preposition
> 5 (used to indicate apposition or identity):
> Is that idiot of a salesman calling again?
>
> (Dictionary.com)

This becomes clear when we look at the image in the article. It's a narrow shop [sandwiched](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sandwich?s=t) between two larger ones.

[image]

Broadly speaking, you could use this *of* metaphorically:

- slip of a girl (slender girl)
- [shadow of a man](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/shadow-of-one-s-self) (weakened man)
- [whale of a](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-whale-of-a) deal (great deal)
- etc.